# StopIteration won't be caught in main()

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, generator, stopiteration

I want to raise a `StopIteration` exception when the number I send is larger than 999999999.

When I sent to `print(check_id_valid(1234567980))` function parameters directly  or to `IDIterator` class (the iterator `class`) and from there the number pass to  `check_id_valid()` function, the exception is catched at the `main()` as it should.
The error string is printed:

```
Reached max number, 1234567980 is over 9 digits
```

But when I send the number to `id_generator()` function (thanks for the previous help its working good),

The `StopIteration` exception wont be raised at the `main()`

```
def check_id_valid(id_number):

     if len(str(id_number)) < 9:
         raise illigalException(id_number)        
     if int(id_number) > 999999999:
         raise StopIteration(id_number)
```

```
def id_generator(Id_number):
   while True:
       Id_number += 1
       if check_id_valid(Id_number):
           yield Id_number
```

```
def main():
 
    id_gen = id_generator(1234567800)
    try:
        for item in range(10):   
            print(next(id_gen))

    except StopIteration as e:
        print("Reached max number, " + str(e)  + " is over 9 digits")
    except (illigalException) as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the error message is -

`raise StopIteration(id_number) StopIteration: 1234567801 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:`

`print(next(id_gen)) RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration`

How can I fix it ?

**P.S**

I need to use the built `StopIteration` exception, not to override it.

Answer (score 2):

Python generator will automatically raise `StopIteration` when it returns. So you shouldn't raise `StopIteration` inside an generator function yourself.

The `StopIteration` is used in iterator to stop the iteration, for example inside a for loop.

```py
def check_id_valid(id_number):

     if len(str(id_number)) < 9:
         raise illigalException(id_number)        
     if int(id_number) > 999999999:
         return False

     # you need to return True if is valid.
     return True


def id_generator(Id_number):
   while True:
       Id_number += 1
       if check_id_valid(Id_number):
           yield Id_number
       
       else:
           # this return here will raise the StopIteration error with message id_number for you.
           return id_number
```

### Update

```py
# assuming your check_id_valid is still the same.
def id_generator(Id_number):
    while True:
        Id_number += 1
        try:
            check_id_valid(Id_number)
        except StopIteration:
            # this return will raise StopIteration when you call next() on id_generator
            return Id_number
        except Exception as e:
            # raise the other illigalException 
            raise e
        
        yield Id_number
```

Comment: I can't return `False`, I need to raise the StopIteration exception. I'm using the  `check_id_valid()` with an Iterator class  and at the `main()` too.

Comment: @Ileh Then you need to catch the `StopIteration` inside the `id_generator`.